# Java How to use groupingSize() with NumberFormat

Tags: java, number-formatting, decimalformat

I am trying to use `DecimalFormat.groupingSize()` functionality with `NumberFormat` class, as I need to have grouping size based on Country like 1,2345,6789 for China, 1,234,567 for Canada or 1,23,450 for India.
I've tried looking for solutions but the solutions are based on `DecimalForamt`. Is there any way we can use `NumberFormat` to resolve this challenge?

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379231/displaying-currency-in-indian-numbering-format and also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34852803/format-currency-in-indian-numbering-format-without-symbol-in-java

Answer (score 0):

DecimalFormat does not allow variable grouping size.

For variable grouping size, use [Icu4J's DecimalFormat](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/#/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
    com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
    com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat df = new com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat("0,00,000", dfs); // indian numbering system
    String s1 = df.format(500000); // 5,00,000
    String s2 = df.format(121212123); // 12,12,12,123
    String s3 = df.format(new com.ibm.icu.math.BigDecimal("67890000000000")); // 6,78,90,00,00,00,000
```

Comment: I need with java.text.NumberFormat, is it possible?

Comment: NumberFormat is superclass of DecimalFormat. It does not support variable grouping size. Use the Icu4J library.